# Clone Failed while trying to checkout from bitbucket https url

Tags: git, android-studio, ssl-certificate, bitbucket, git-clone

I tried to clone a repository from bitbucket in android studio through options

VCS->Checkout from version control->git.

It asked me for the url which I copied from bitbucket repo path & press ok, It gives me the following error then:

Clone failed
fatal: unable to access 'https://user_name@bitbucket.org/Dir/repo_name.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

But when I tried it in Eclipse and Git shell, it is working perfectly. Can any one help me to get rid of this in Android studio. Even one of my peer is able to access this on android studio.
fyi, I am behind an organization's firewall so my peer is who is successfully did this.

stuck on this, can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of my proxy settings in git config. You can check them using git config --list command , and can make changes as per your need in http.proxy